# NOT IN use in same table

Tags: mysql

im kinda new to the site, as a user atleast, been finding my answers in here for a long time :)

My problem is this, i work at a rather big hospital, where we run a mysql db containing all our employees, and now i need to make a query that can show my all employees who's employment ended during 2017. The thing is, since its a big hospital where ALOT of departments alot of the employees change jobs internally between the different departments, and everytime they do a new row in the table is created with their new employment details.

in every row for every employment, it contains their employer ID, the start date and end date, and some other info. the end date, can be either a date ofc, it can be NULL or 0000-00-00, the last 2 indicates that their imployment has no end date.

So its easy enough to do a simple search containing all users with and end date containing 2017

```
 (SELECT * FROM table WHERE enddate LIKE '%2017%')
```

and it gives me all the users who has an end date in 2017, problem is ofc, that it does not account for users who might just have switched department, and has ended its employment in one department to start in another.

So what im trying to do is get all users with a 2017 enddate and then all people that has no enddate or and enddate after 2017 and then remove them from the list of people with an 2017 enddate.

i tried the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE enddate LIKE '%2017%' AND employid NOT IN
(
SELECT * FROM users WHERE enddate LIKE '%0000%'
);
```

i know it doesnt really over all i wanted, but at first i was really just trying to get the NOT IN to work in some way, and then after that work my way on to include the rest, but i cant even get that to work.

I tried searching for some uses of NOT IN, but it seemed to always be some very simple uses of them and always on 2 different tables.

I hope i explained it correct, as stated im still kinda new to mysql and sql in general :)

Comment: It would help if you provided an SQL script that sets up a DB table with example data, that would illustrate much better what kind of data you're dealing with and it would allow people to test solutions instead of just hoping they guessed your structure correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the NOT IN Problem you can use this query:

```
 SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE enddate LIKE '%2017%' AND employid NOT IN 
( SELECT employid FROM users WHERE ansslut LIKE '%0000%' );
```

Note that inside the NOT IN Select you must specify the "employid" field.

See if this work for you

Comment: i edited my first "test" i saw i made a mistake with the enddate and ansslut, it should be enddate in both, but i tried your version, and atleast it gave me some return data, and seems to work, now ofc i just have to make sure its right :) but thx any way, it seems to work so far :)

Answer (score 0):

You are matching for a column and the you shoul return a comparable value from the subselect related to NOT  IN 
eg asssuming you emp_id match with user id from you r subselect you should

```
  SELECT *
  FROM users
  WHERE enddate LIKE '%2017%' 
      AND employid NOT IN (
        SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE ansslut LIKE '%0000%'
  );
```